# Number of feature maps do not increase after each block of 3D Resnet

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am trying to build 3D Resnet for small 3D patches of size [32,32,44] with one channel. In 2D Resnet, after each residual block, the size of images should reduce to half and the number of feature maps doubles as shown below

```
# function for creating an identity or projection residual module
def residual_module(layer_in, n_filters):
    merge_input = layer_in
    # check if the number of filters needs to be increase, assumes channels last format
    if layer_in.shape[-1] != n_filters:
        merge_input = Conv2D(n_filters, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer_in)
    # conv1
    conv1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer_in)
    # conv2
    conv2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='linear', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    # add filters, assumes filters/channels last
    layer_out = add([conv2, merge_input])
    # activation function
    layer_out = Activation('relu')(layer_out)
    return layer_out
 
# define model input
visible = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
layer = residual_module(visible,64)
layer_1 = residual_module(layer,128)
# create model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=layer_1)
# summarize model
model.summary()
```

Result:

```
Model: "model_44"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_68 (InputLayer)           [(None, 256, 256, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_40 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 640         input_68[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_41 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 36928       conv2d_40[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_39 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 64) 128         input_68[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_207 (Add)                   (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           conv2d_41[0][0]                  
                                                                 conv2d_39[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_52 (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           add_207[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_43 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 128 73856       activation_52[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_44 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 128 147584      conv2d_43[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_42 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 128 8320        activation_52[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_208 (Add)                   (None, 256, 256, 128 0           conv2d_44[0][0]                  
                                                                 conv2d_42[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_53 (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 128 0           add_208[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 267,456
Trainable params: 267,456
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

However, adapting this code for 3D Resnet does not double the number of feature maps. As it can be seen in the below example that after first residual block channel dimension is still 1 and changes to 3 in the second block

```
def residual_module(layer_in, n_filters):
    merge_input = layer_in
    # check if the number of filters needs to be increase, assumes channels last format
    if layer_in.shape[-1] != n_filters:
        merge_input = Conv3D(n_filters, (1,1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer_in)
    # conv1
    conv1 = Conv3D(n_filters, (3,3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer_in)
    # conv2
    conv2 = Conv3D(n_filters, (3,3,3), padding='same', activation='linear', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    # add filters, assumes filters/channels last
    layer_out = add([conv2, merge_input])
    # activation function
    layer_out = Activation('relu')(layer_out)
    return layer_out
 
# define model input
visible = Input(shape=(32,32,32,1))
layer = residual_module(visible,16)
layer_1 = residual_module(layer,32)
# create model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=layer_1)
# summarize model
model.summary()
```

Result:

```
Model: "model_45"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_69 (InputLayer)           [(None, 32, 32, 32,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_519 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 1 448         input_69[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_520 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 1 6928        conv3d_519[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_518 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 1 32          input_69[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_209 (Add)                   (None, 32, 32, 32, 1 0           conv3d_520[0][0]                 
                                                                 conv3d_518[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_54 (Activation)      (None, 32, 32, 32, 1 0           add_209[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_522 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 3 13856       activation_54[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_523 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 3 27680       conv3d_522[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_521 (Conv3D)             (None, 32, 32, 32, 3 544         activation_54[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_210 (Add)                   (None, 32, 32, 32, 3 0           conv3d_523[0][0]                 
                                                                 conv3d_521[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_55 (Activation)      (None, 32, 32, 32, 3 0           add_210[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 49,488
Trainable params: 49,488
Non-trainable params: 0
_______________________________________________________________________________________________
```

What  am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out that the code is okay, except that the lines in model.summary() were truncated, so in fact feature maps in the first residual block are 16 and in the second they are 32. Increasing line_width was the catch

```
model.summary(line_length=110)
```

Results:

```
Model: "model_8"
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                        Output Shape            Param #      Connected to                         
==============================================================================================================
input_9 (InputLayer)                [(None, 32, 32, 32, 1)] 0                                                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_136 (Conv3D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32, 16)  448          input_9[0][0]                        
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_137 (Conv3D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32, 16)  6928         conv3d_136[0][0]                     
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_135 (Conv3D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32, 16)  32           input_9[0][0]                        
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_57 (Add)                        (None, 32, 32, 32, 16)  0            conv3d_137[0][0]                     
                                                                         conv3d_135[0][0]                     
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_113 (Activation)         (None, 32, 32, 32, 16)  0            add_57[0][0]                         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_139 (Conv3D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32, 32)  13856        activation_113[0][0]                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_140 (Conv3D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32, 32)  27680        conv3d_139[0][0]                     
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_138 (Conv3D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32, 32)  544          activation_113[0][0]                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_58 (Add)                        (None, 32, 32, 32, 32)  0            conv3d_140[0][0]                     
                                                                         conv3d_138[0][0]                     
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_114 (Activation)         (None, 32, 32, 32, 32)  0            add_58[0][0]                         
==============================================================================================================
Total params: 49,488
Trainable params: 49,488
Non-trainable params: 0
```